U24.04 mouse does not work on occasion in certain applications more
Upgraded to 24.04 2 days ago. Noticed that in certain applications and on certain occasions, left mouse click causes the app to minimize instead of doing the right action. I changed from Wayland to X11 and it did work fine for a while. Then same phenomenon. Then I switched from X11 to Wayland, it's OK for now. But I'm nearly certain this is NOT the end of the story. Any idea guys?

does it do this when you click anywhere or just in the title bar?

Please read again my issue first. But now all I have to do to fix the issue is to execute systemctl restart gdm3 without changing between wayland and X11. This is a bug with 24.04 that must be addressed.

So you click the left mouse on the background of the screen and your application to minimize?  or something else?  Depending on where you click, it is suppose to minimize.
